# Define a date offset from today for a batch report

Tags: algorithm, encoding, formatting

I have to make a report that will execute automatically several times, every day, with different settings. The report selects records between two dates. Now, the client wants to be free to define, in a text or excel file, the dates that will run each report. For example, every day I want to run the report for that day, and for that same day the previous year, and for the same day the previous week, and for the previous week, and for the next month of the previous year. Then on the first of every month, the whole previous month, etc. I think you get the gist.

My question is: Is there any established way of doing this? Some text encoding for offsets of dates? I've looked and nothing appears. However, it doesn't seem an outlandish proposition. I suppose the situation has happened before. I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel. If, however, there is nothing, any idea would be welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I did it myself, no free lunch this time :-) The format I chose is a string like:

+1W,fW,-1D (That would be the next week, first day of that week, then one day before that)

Separator is comma, keys are D for day, W for week, M for month, Y for year, F for first, L for Last (all keys can be lower or upper case). The format ignores whitespace, but the last non-whitespace character must be a key. Only integer offsets allowed.

I give my first implementation of a VBA function that interprets a text offset. It seems to work, although little testing done yet.

Well, that's all, for posterity.

---

```
 Public Function GetDateFromOffset(fecIni As Date, sDif As String) As Date
    Dim sArr() As String, ii As Integer, fRes As Date
    fRes = fecIni
    sArr = Split(sDif, ",")

    For ii = LBound(sArr()) To UBound(sArr())
        fRes = ApplyOneOffset(fRes, sArr(ii))
    Next ii

    GetDateFromOffset = fRes
End Function

Public Function ApplyOneOffset(fecIni As Date, sDif As String) As Date
    Const C_DAY As String = "D", C_WEEK As String = "W", C_MONTH As String = "M", C_YEAR As String = "Y"
    Const C_FIRST As String = "F", C_LAST As String = "L"

    Dim iDesp As Integer, sDesp As String, fRes As Date
    sDesp = UCase(Right(sDif, 1))
    sDif = Trim(UCase(Left(sDif, Len(sDif) - 1)))
    Select Case sDesp
        Case C_DAY
            If (IsNumeric(sDif)) Then
                fRes = DateAdd("d", CInt(sDif), fecIni)
            End If
        Case C_WEEK
            If (sDif = C_FIRST) Then
                fRes = dhFirstDayInWeek(fecIni)
            ElseIf (sDif = C_LAST) Then
                fRes = dhLastDayInWeek(fecIni)
            ElseIf (IsNumeric(sDif)) Then
                fRes = DateAdd("ww", CInt(sDif), fecIni)
            End If
        Case C_MONTH
            If (sDif = C_FIRST) Then
                fRes = dhFirstDayInMonth(fecIni)
            ElseIf (sDif = C_LAST) Then
                fRes = dhLastDayInMonth(fecIni)
            ElseIf (IsNumeric(sDif)) Then
                fRes = DateAdd("m", CInt(sDif), fecIni)
            End If
        Case C_YEAR
            If (sDif = C_FIRST) Then
                fRes = DateSerial(YEAR(fecIni), 1, 1)
            ElseIf (sDif = C_LAST) Then
                fRes = DateSerial(YEAR(fecIni), 31, 12)
            ElseIf (IsNumeric(sDif)) Then
                fRes = DateAdd("yyyy", CInt(sDif), fecIni)
            End If
        Case Else
            fRes = fecIni
    End Select

    ApplyOneOffset = fRes

End Function
```